# Arch Linux display Xorg not function at all, but Wayland does (very poorly). Corrupted Xorg files from mirror?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, pacman, download, corruption

Hello fellow Linux users,

I recently purchased an old laptop and decided to try Arch Linux. I bought it to see just how well Arch is for a system and also due to the fact of my main PC's HDD is giving out, leading me to a read only file system. I need a system I can use and I can't get the login managers to work. **The HDD in the machine has been tested and no errors were found.** I have gone as far as to try using *xorg-xinit* and the server is considered corrupt. My guess is an issue with either the pacman mirror or the download itself. Either way I'd like a lightweight graphical UI like XFCE4 or MATE but the display managers are all corrupt. Do I need to change the mirrors? If not how do I fix the corrupted download errors?

---

**Update**

I have discovered that most of the packages are intact by installing htop and neofetch and running them. So I can confirm that the mirror is intact. However **I am not sure what I am running for repository mirrors because I did not configure the mirrors. I do know that it's the default ones.**

---

**Update 2**

Found GDM was the only one to work and so does GNOME 3 on Wayland, but it's far too heavy for my hardware, utilizing just too much resources to use at all. When I try to start XFCE or MATE, I get looked back to the GDM screen. I even refreshed my pgp keys and system update. Nothing. I want to try KDE but it will also be slow.. as it turns out, Xorg if where my issue lies. That particular package is corrupt and I don't know why.

Comment: Why don't you ask here? https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewforum.php?id=18

Comment: when ever I installed Arch in the last 10 years it always worked - if you follow the wiki! If something does not work, I would consider the error is on your side first. Assuming that one of the major distros, used by thousands of people day by day is just nonsense! Read the wiki and ask the Arch forum. There is also a IRC channel with arch (sometimes a bit ruide in my opinion)

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand - is it login loop?

Comment: Essentially the Xorg server has corrupted upon download. I downloaded over LAN and my HDD had been tested and is ok. There is an issue with Xorg itself and that is why Wayland GDM and GNOME ran (very poorly due to my hardware specs).

Comment: And setting it up was done exactly as followed from the official ArchWiki site with variations made for Eastern/Atlantic United States  region settings

Comment: PS: have you changed the mirror / tested another one?

Comment: Yes I tested a few but they didn't work. I wonder if Xorg if intact on a non US mirror? Ok the meantime, can I port MATE or XFCE to Wayland or another GUI server?